# Django REST: How to PUT Data in Nested ModelSerializer (Update)

Tags: python, django, put

Now I can POST a new data to my django app by json ,but can't update the data or delete it. I try to override the update method in the serializer.py, but it still doesn't work. The data keep original values.

**My question is how to update all the data at once and delete data individual such as subtaskdata, friendsdata or chatroomdata.**

part of my serializer.py

```
class SubtaskDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SubtaskData
        fields = ("subtask_name","subtask_deadline","subtask_completion",
              "subtask_importance","subtask_item")
        depth = 3

class TaskDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    SubtaskDatas = SubtaskDataSerializer( many = True )
    class Meta:
        model = TaskData
        fields = ("task_name", "task_is_group",
              "task_time", "task_score", "task_member_list",
              "task_bulletin","SubtaskDatas")
        read_only_fields = ('SubtaskDatas',)
        depth = 2                

class FriendsDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = FriendsData
        fields = ("friend_name","friend_account")
        depth = 2


class UserDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    TaskDatas = TaskDataSerializer( many = True )
    FriendsDatas = FriendsDataSerializer( many = True )
    ChatroomDatas = ChatroomDataSerializer( many = True )
    photo = Base64ImageField(
        max_length=None, use_url=True,
    )
    class Meta:
        model = UserData
        fields = ("pk","account","password","username","gender","score",
              "photo","TaskDatas","FriendsDatas","ChatroomDatas")
        read_only_fields = ('TaskDatas','FriendsDatas','ChatroomDatas',)
        depth = 1
```

views.py

```
@api_view(['GET','POST'])
def jobterm_list(request, format=None):

    if request.method=="GET":
        UserDatas =list(UserData.objects.all()) 
        serializer = UserDataSerializer(UserDatas,many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)


    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = UserDataSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors,     status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)



@api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE']) #
def jobterm_detial(request,pk, format=None):
    try:
        User_Data = UserData.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except UserData.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == "GET":
        serializer = UserDataSerializer(User_Data)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == "PUT":
        serializer = UserDataSerializer(User_Data,data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    elif request.method == "DELETE":
        User_Data.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I try to define update() method accordingly like this.

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):  
    instance.account = validated_data['account']
    instance.password = validated_data['password']
    instance.username = validated_data['username']
    instance.gender = validated_data['gender']
    instance.score = validated_data['score']
    instance.photo = validated_data['photo']

    Friends_Datas = User_Datas.get('FriendsDatas')
    for friend in Friends_Datas:
        friendsdatas, _ = FriendsData.objects.update_or_create(
            {'friend_name': friend.get('friend_name')},
            friend_account = friend.get('friend_account'),
            usersData_id = instance)

    Task_Datas = User_Datas.get('TaskDatas')
    for task in Task_Datas:
        taskdatas, _  = TaskData.objects.update_or_create(
            {
            'task_is_group' : task.get('task_is_group'),
            'task_time' : task.get('task_time'),
            'task_score' : task.get('task_score'),
            'task_member_list' : task.get('task_member_list'), 
            'task_bulletin' : task.get('task_bulletin'),   },
            task_name = task.get('task_name'),
            userData_id = instance
                                    )
        Subtask_Datas = task.get('SubtaskDatas')
        for subtask in Subtask_Datas:
            subtaskdatas = SubtaskData.objects.update_or_create(
                {'subtask_deadline' : subtask.get('subtask_deadline'), 
                'subtask_completion' : subtask.get('subtask_completion'), 
                'subtask_importance' : subtask.get('subtask_importance'), 
                'subtask_item' : subtask.get('subtask_item'), }
                ,subtask_name = subtask.get('subtask_name'), 
                taskData_id = taskdatas                
                                    )


    Chatroom_Datas = User_Datas.get('ChatroomDatas')
    for chatroom in Chatroom_Datas:
        chatroomdatas, _  = ChatroomData.objects.update_or_create(
            {'chatroom_contents' : chatroom.get('chatroom_contents'),},
            chatroom_member = chatroom.get('chatroom_member'), 
            userdata_cid = instance
             )

    return instance
```